# Default DB Size of Heroku App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, default

I am pretty new to web dev and thought I needed a 20gb shared db in order to test out apps that have larger than 5mb stored.

My friend let me know this was not true because I am using single app. He told me shared dbs were used for sharing data between multiple applications.

If so, what is Heroku's default, unshared db size? I had difficulty in finding this information on Heroku's website and google searches.

Could anyone chime in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shared database in this case means the server itself is shared -- so the server's CPU will be used to serve other databases in addition to your own.

A dedicated database server's CPU's are yours and yours alone.

If you need to exceed the 5MB threshold, you need to add the 20GB add on. More information: http://www.heroku.com/pricing

Comment: From what I understand, my app is part of multiple dbs which is capped at 5mb and processed by one of heroku's server. Thus, if I wanted to start a blog that contains more than 5mb of content to call and render, I would need the 20gb add-on, correct?